# How to center node on tree and force graph - d3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js, zooming

I've implemented geometric zooming on a force graph as well as an indented tree.

This allows panning and zooming. Now, I need to navigate to pre-elected node, which should bring that node in the center of the viewpoint.

As I understand, I would need to calculate the distance of the node to the `svg` center, and move each of the nodes and edges for the same distance.
I am not sure if this is the right approach.

Please let me know if I am on the right track.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21843206/d3-force-layout-fix-root-node-at-the-center or https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/bmASQY9v1MM or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362894/center-force-directed-layout-after-tick-using-root-node-return-to-center

Comment: this may also help : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3828981

Comment: +1 @AJ_91 thank you. Now I need to figure out how to pass the translation to the existing zoom listener. Otherwise the next zoom jumps to the previous location.

Comment: set up a JSFiddle, may we could give it a try :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center force directed layout after tick using root node (return to center)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362894/center-force-directed-layout-after-tick-using-root-node-return-to-center)