# d3 force layout with click-to-zoom into specific node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to combine click-to-zoom functionality (e.g. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590) with d3's force layout (e.g. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130).  The idea being that after clicking on a node in a force layout diagram, a zoom transition is applied with the node clicked moving to the centre (while any other force-related "tick-ing" is also allowed to continue).

Does anyone know of existing examples combining these pieces of functionality?  I've been trying to adapt the click-to-zoom example myself but although the clicked() function seems pretty simple, I'm stuck on the role of the "path" variable and how it seems to be linked to here...

```
g.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("id", "state-borders")
      .attr("d", path);
```

For example, I have a force layout where all nodes/links are appended to a parent g-element, do I really need an equivalent datum line above?  And what is the function of the d attribute that the path variable is being fed into?  I know I'm doing something wrong because at the moment when the clicked function evaluates "path.centroid(d)" it's always NaN.

Thanks for any thoughts at all!

Adding my current simplified implementation of automated click/zoom (triggered from within my nodeClick function) that works perfectly until the force layout moves nodes further (due to paramaters like charge, gravity, friction etc)...

```
var k;

        if (d && centered !== d) {
            k = 4;
            centered = d;
        } else {
            k = 1;
            centered = null;
        }

        svg.transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -d.x + "," + -d.y + ")");
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362894/center-force-directed-layout-after-tick-using-root-node-return-to-center) and [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/bmASQY9v1MM) may help.

Comment: thanks Lars. I got something basic working by just following the mouse position (d.x, d.y) instead of actually linking directly to nodes.  The problem I have now is that the centre/zoom functionality is correct at the point of applying it, but soon becomes incorrect after the force layout's tick function has adjusted positions of all the nodes.  Do you know how I could identify the equivalent of d.x and d.y for a specific node so that I could follow it throughout the tick function and zoom more intelligently as the force parameters evolve?

Comment: Well in principle all you need to do is centre the node and apply a scale transformation to the force layout container to zoom in. This should work fine with any changes to the force layout afterwards. How did you implement the zoom?

Comment: Thanks Lars - I just added my implementation of the automated zoom/centre at the end of my original post.  Just to clarify that it works perfectly in a sense - the only problem is that since the force layout is continuously moving nodes (until the last tick), my centre point for the node in question quickly becomes outdated

Comment: What do you mean by "outdated"? The node you've centred should remain there.

Comment: Sorry Lars - I meant that the node moves because on my click behaviour I also add children (attached to the parent with links) - that basically throws the nodes I clicked on around a little and means my "centre" is no longer accurate.

Comment: Ok, so what do you actually mean by "centre"? Not the centre of the container?